# Add class to the radio buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, javascript, jquery

I have a radio button in the Product View page at the custom options, this contain Hide and Show. Is there any way to add a class for each option? I need to hide everything that is under this field when the value Hide is checked and to display when select Show. I try to use this but is work only for hide.

```
     jQuery('div:contains("Show")').on('click', function(){
       jQuery(this).closest('dd').siblings().show();
    });
     jQuery('div:contains("Hide")').on('click', function(){
       jQuery(this).closest('dd').siblings().hide();
    });
```

PHP code for generate radio buttons:

```
                       $selectHtml .= '<li><input type="radio" id="options_' . $_option->getId() . '" class="'
                            . $class . ' product-custom-option" name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"'
                            . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
                            . ' value="" checked="checked" /><span class="label"><label for="options_'
                            . $_option->getId() . '">' . $this->__('None') . '</label></span></li>';
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Comment: here is the entire HTML http://pastebin.com/xMRzcfXR

Comment: It is not clear... I do not see any Show/Hide, can you please explain better your problem?

Comment: please take a look here? https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/hy3r9kn4/ at the top is two radio buttons, that is for show and and hide, the all process must be work like in this fiddle but I need to identify that radio buttons, because if you know magento you know that the radios buttons id is something like this: id="options_' . $_option->getId() . '" so I need to add a class or something to can add a jquery code.

Comment: please tell me if everything is clear for you

Comment: look I edit my post

Comment: from here are generate that radio buttons, how I can add a class? maybe with an increment variable for each option to access this in the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You need to add a custom field to your custom options and use it in your frontend.

Have a look here to understand how to add a new field:

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

Then you will have to take that field's value and use for your css class in frontend.

**Option 2**

According to the snippet you gave and the additional information on your comments you can use the JavaScript approach:

```
var showRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input');
var hideRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(2)').find('input');

hideRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').show();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();
})
showRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').show();
})
```

Comment: I have that already added, but that is for the entire radio field, I need for each option, because I need to identify the option to can hide and show with jquery

Comment: Check the article, it is for each option.

Comment: like this is very incomod for client to complete this fields again, i need to find an direct solution, a global

Comment: Do you need this solution based on the field content or for its position? Please specify what you need.

Comment: let's talk on skype i will add you now